# How to make Gson parse integer to integer instead of double or float?

Tags: java, json, gson

I run into a issue that I can't de-serialize a integer of json string. Instead, I got only float(or double?) when came with numbers, which should be a int when it like `12` and a float(or double) when it like `12.0` right? Gson doesn't do that properly. Here is what I googled and got, but things still the same:

```
public class TestRedis {
    private static class MyObjectDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Object> {

        public Object deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
                throws JsonParseException {
            Number num = null;
            try {
                num = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //ignore
            }
            if (num == null) {
                return context.deserialize(json, typeOfT);
            } else {
                return num;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] argvs){
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("a",1);
        m.put("b",2);

        //serilize to json string
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String s = gson.toJson(m);
        System.out.println(s);

        //deserilize now...
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson1 = builder.create();
        builder.registerTypeAdapter(Object.class, new MyObjectDeserializer());
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
        Map<String, Object> mm = gson1.fromJson(s,type);
        System.out.println(mm);
    }
}
```

And here is the output of above program:

```
{"b":2,"a":1}
{b=2.0, a=1.0}
```

Clearly gson make has mistook integer as double or float

---

For those who probably suggest make a *structure* which indicates the real type of corresponding value, well, I can't, because the real type I deal with is `Map<String, Object>` the value of this map could be any type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Json String contain integer value , while deserialize to HashMap, Integer convert into double values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256397/json-string-contain-integer-value-while-deserialize-to-hashmap-integer-conver)